# Creating a data frame conditional on another data frame R with lapply or other function

Tags: r, lapply

I'm trying to create a data frame conditional on another frame on every single element.

For example:

```
c0 <- c(0.1,0.2,0.5,.1)
c1 <- c(0.1,0.2,0.5,.1)
c2 <- c(0.1,0.2,0.5,.1)
c3 <- c(0.1,0.2,0.5,.1)
c4 <- c(0.1,0.2,0.5,.1)
df <- data.frame(c0,c1,c2,c3,c4)
colnames(df)<-c("A","B","C","D","E")
rownames(df)<-c("A","B","C","D")
```

This will give me a data frame like this:

```
> df
    A   B   C   D   E
A 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1
B 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
D 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1
```

Now I want to find if any element is greater than 0.5 if else replace with 0 in a new dataframe:

```
> df.Indicator <- as.data.frame(lapply(as.matrix(df),function(x) 
+                  ifelse(x>=0.50,1,0)))
> df.Indicator
  X0 X0.1 X1 X0.2 X0.3 X0.4 X1.1 X0.5 X0.6 X0.7 X1.2 X0.8 X0.9 X0.10 X1.3 X0.11 X0.12 X0.13 X1.4 X0.14
1  0    0  1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     0    1     0     0     0    1     0
```

I would like to get back a data-frame with indicators on same mxn like this

```
    A   B   C   D   E
A  0    0   0   0   0
B  0    0   0   0   0
C  1    1   1   1   1
D  0    0   0   0   0
```

This is a simple example but eventually I would like to establish more conditions.

Thank you!

Comment: `(df >= 0.5) * 1`

Answer (score 1):

The replacement you need does not require `lapply` or a function. Try the following code.

```
df[df >= 0.5] <- 1
df[df != 1] <- 0
```

Or as suggested by others. Use the following code.

```
df <- (df >= 0.5) * 1
```

If you really want to use `apply` family function, here is a modification of your original code. Use `apply`, not `lapply`.

```
df <- as.data.frame(apply(df, 2, function(x) ifelse(x >= 0.5, 1, 0)))
```

Here is another solution from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate_all(funs(ifelse(. >= 0.5, 1, 0)))
```

Comment: or you can multiply the logical values and get result straight away like this `df <- (df>=0.5)*1`

Comment: @jyr I like this approach. Thanks for sharing. I will update this approach to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. It was actually the `as.matrix` statement now it works as desired, without that:

```
df.Indicator <- as.data.frame(lapply(df,function(x) 

   ifelse(x>=0.50,1,0)))

> df.Indicator
  A B C D E
1 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0
3 1 1 1 1 1
4 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: This is fine, but notice that the row name is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Data in put

```
c0 <- c(0.1,0.2,0.5,.1)
c1 <- c(0.1,0.2,0.5,.1)
c2 <- c(0.1,0.2,0.5,.1)
c3 <- c(0.1,0.2,0.5,.1)
c4 <- c(0.1,0.2,0.5,.1)
df <- data.frame(c0,c1,c2,c3,c4)
colnames(df)<-c("A","B","C","D","E")
rownames(df)<-c("A","B","C","D")

A=data.frame(df>=0.5)

data.frame(lapply(A, as.numeric), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  A B C D E
1 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0
3 1 1 1 1 1
4 0 0 0 0 0
```